# What are the best ways to save data for the project without using database?

Tags: json, reactjs, graphql, frontend, gatsby

I am developing a small front end e commerce project using **gatsby**, I want to save my shopping items (10 - 15) data in somewhere else but not in database because it is front end only project. I don't want to hardcode the items in jsx because I think it's a bad practice, so I am thinking to manually writing down all item details in json files like this

```
{
"name": "ps4",
"price": "$400",
},
...
```

and use graphQL to get those data back. I wanna know is it a good way to do it or is there any better way to achieve ?

Comment: As you said - `*.json` file. In my opinion it is handy and easy to maintain due to it's separation.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on your use case. If there are not too many different products, they don't change that often and the only one updating the list is you, then I think putting them in a file together with the code is fine.

If, however, non-developers need to be able to change the list, it is a very long list or the list changes often, I think it would be better to leave it outside the code. It doesn't need to be a database, you could use an online service such as Shopify or Airtable.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out shopify and Airtable as well.

Comment: That's just two random examples. There's any number of SaaS solutions where you could store the data and pull it from. You can probably get some ideas by looking at what source plugins Gatsby offers.

Answer (score 0):

It depends...

- gatsby source can be almost anything (json/yaml/md/js/graphql/rest/WP/....);
- data (default) is available using graphQL **only during build**;
- **data update need gatsby project rebuild/redeploy**;

If you need to generate page for every product and want them generated (SEO reasons) rebuilding is neccessary.

Of course you can mix it (hybrid solution) with dynamic data/parts like prices/stock.

If you want to read entire/part product data from dynamic sources:

- you can use graphQL or simple json files as data source;
- you can use Apollo client for **runtime graphQL fetching**  but it needs graphQL server/source (API) - (gatsby internally works as a graphql source/'server'+client but only during build);
- **you can use simple/lightweight `fetch/ajax` to load json data from file but also from graphql sources**;